# PHP : Check and Read from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like :-

```
$arr = array(
    "Sci-Fi",
    "Action"
);
```

How can check if `Action` exists in this array , And how can convert it to `(Sci-Fi,Action)`

Thankx

Comment: Use php on-line documentation. You could use [in-array](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.in-array.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question $arr is the array.  First we'll check if 'Action' is in the array.

```
    if(in_array('Action',$arr)){
      //in_array checks if 'Action' is in the array
      echo "Action is in the array!";
    }
```

Now we need to "implode" the array to turn it into a string.

```
    echo "(" . implode(',', $arr) . ")";
    //implode glues the parts of your array together into a string using the supplied "glue", in this case a comma.
```

php.net has it all documented, but I know it's hard to just know what a function name is, especially something cryptic like implode.  When you're learning it's nice to get a friendly answer.

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: I usually post the answer and then edit it to add a better explanation.  If I write it all up before hand somebody will beat me with a simple answer.  So quick answer for the OP, then explanation for the good of the group.  It's one of the many awful behaviors encouraged the horrible stack overflow policies.  Don't hate the player, hate the game.

Comment: I don't hate anything. I don't know every single SO user habits, I act of good will for the community. It was just a polite reminder, not a personal rant.

Comment: Ok, understood, it's all good.

Comment: i try to `echo "(" . implode(',', $arr) . ")";` but not show me any result, But i try this  `foreach($AdsPage as $item) { echo $item.',';}` and show result

Comment: Then your array is named $AdsPage....not $arr as used in your example code.  You can use `echo "(" . implode(',', $AdsPage) . ")";` in this case.